# JS Slider for images - Is there an easier way to do it?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was able to make this work, but I believe I made it really dirty work here. I was wondering, is there a simpler way to do this. I'm asking for learning purposes.

Fetch is pulling json objects and the objects have an image array in them, then populates the content inside their own containers with the images. I tried to make it switch between the images with prev and next buttons.

Every container holds 4 or 5 different images.

Here is my code. I tried to stick with ES6. I don't want to use jquery on this one.

```
fetch('./public/js/projects.json')
.then((Response) => {
return Response.json();
}).then((data) => {
const projects = data.projects;

projects.map((project, index) => {
    const container_projects = document.getElementById('projects');
    const project_img = project.img

    const markup_project = `
    <div class="project" aria-label="${index}">
        <div class="project_image">
            <div class="arrow_container">
                <button class="arrows left_arrow"><img src="assets/svg/left_arrow.svg" class="left"/></button>
                <div class="numbers">
                    <span class="current">1</span>
                    <span class="divider">/</span>
                    <span class="total">${project_img.length}</span>
                </div>
                <button class="arrows right_arrow"><img src="assets/svg/right_arrow.svg" class="right"/></button>
            </div>
            <div class="image_container">
                ${project_img.map(image => `<img src="${image}" class=""/>`).join('')}
            </div>
        </div>
        <small class="project_name">${project.title}</small>
    </div>
    `               
    container_projects.innerHTML += markup_project;         
})          

return projects
}).then((data) => {


data.map((project, index) => {
    const current_project = document.querySelectorAll(`.project`);
    const images = [].slice.call(current_project[index].querySelectorAll('.image_container img'));
    const arrows = current_project[index].querySelectorAll('.arrows');
    const current = current_project[index].querySelector('.current');

    images[0].classList.add('active');

    arrows.forEach((arrow) => {
        arrow.addEventListener('click', (e) => {


            let num;
            images.map((image, index)=> {

                if (image.classList.contains('active')){
                    image.classList.remove('active');   

                    if (e.target.className == 'right'){
                        num = index + 1
                    } else {
                        num = index - 1
                    }   

                    if (num >= images.length){
                        num = 0;                            
                    } 
                    else if (num <= -1 ){
                        num = images.length - 1
                    }


                    console.log(num)
                    return num;
                }
                return num;
            })

            images[num].classList.add('active');
            current.innerHTML = num + 1;



        });
    })
})
}).catch((error) => {
console.log(error);
})
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Likely more suitable for codereview

Comment: Some observations: classList.toggle is useful; several opportunities for ternaries in your code such as `num = index + e.target.className == 'right'+1:-1;` - also since you use e.target elsewhere, why not add the event listener to the arrow container instead of looping over two arrows

Comment: Assuming the fetch works, you could post an array of images from placeholder or lorempixel and produce a [mcve] using the snippet editor (click edit, the the icon that looks like `[<>]` but since there is not really a question here suited for Stackoverflow, it will likely be voted down and closed